# Form Validation Submits the Form too

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I'm working on my custom module that has a form having an email field and I'm using drupal 8's ajax form validation to validate the email whether it exists in the database already or not. But the problem is even if it finds the entered email in the database and throws error but it submits the form as well. This is happening in the ajax validation which i am triggering on forms submit click. If I remove the ajax validation and do the validation like normal, it works perfect.
Using Drupal 8.2.6

Question is why it's submitting the form on ajax validation? It found the email is duplicate shows the error then it should not submit the form. Why is it happening? Can anyone help?

```
$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
  '#type'=>'submit',
  '#value'=>'Subscribe',
  '#attributes'=>array(
    'class'=>['button--primary']
    ),
  '#ajax'=>array(
    'callback'=>array($this, 'ajaxValidateEmail'),
    'event'=>'click'
    ),
  '#suffix'=>'<div class="email-error-message"></div>',
  );
```

And here is the ajaxValidateEmail itself.

```
public function ajaxValidateEmail(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$email = $form_state->getValue('email');
$table = 'subscribe_subscribers';
$query = db_select($table, 'subscriber')
        ->fields('subscriber')
        ->condition('email',$email,'=')
        ->condition('status',1)
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAssoc();
if ($query) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('.email-error-message', $this->t('Email already exists.')));
  return $response;
 }
}
```

[image: Found the email and thrown error]

[image: entered the druplicate email as well which is because it submitted the form too]

Comment: Anyone? Having the same issue?